# Android & Js Communication problems (Uncaught Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation)

Tags: javascript, android, database

I am creating an app. I add a html, css and js file into the webview. I also build up several databases (sqldatabase) to store data. Js is used to add, delete and update data in databases. The reason why I build database is that app will be killed in the background after the user had click "home" button for while. Databases can help rebuild the whole html and continue running the app.

I succeed in building the webview and database. Everything runs smoothly when I run the app. However, problem occurs when the app is killed and I continue using the app. Firstly, the app knows how to rebuild the whole html by data extracted from the databases. However, the app crashes when I continue the operation: add, delete, update data in databases. The following error is given:

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(5841)] "Uncaught Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation", source: file:///android_asset/index.html (5841)
```

Here is the js which crashed during operation:

```
app.delete_duty(String(myVar[4 * a]));
```

and here is the java corresponds to the js above:

```
 @JavascriptInterface
public void delete_duty(String id)
{
        myDB2.deleteData(id); // myDB2 is one of the database that I stored data
}
```

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    HTMLDataBase myDB1;
    ContentTableDataBase myDB2;
    CloudTableDataBase myDB3;
    InterviewDataBase myDB4;
    Context context;
    boolean check;

    private WebView view;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myDB1 = new HTMLDataBase(this);
        myDB2 = new ContentTableDataBase(this);
        myDB3 = new CloudTableDataBase(this); 
        myDB4 = new InterviewDataBase(this); 

        display_html();
        Javascript_Android_Communication();
    }

    public void display_html()
    {
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    public void Javascript_Android_Communication()
    {
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
        WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        view.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
        view.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewJavaScriptInterface(this), "app");
    }
}
```

I doubt the problem comes from the communication between java and javascript as everything is fine if the app is not killed. That means before the app is killed, javascript runs smoothly without any problem. However, error appears with the same script after the app is killed and the html is rebuilt.

Comment: when the app rebuilds the whole html from database, does it also re-initialize javascript? if not, this line `app.delete_duty(String(myVar[4 * a]));` will call `delete_duty()` passing a null ID

Comment: YES, it does re-initialize the whole javascript

Comment: What shall I do if it does not re-initalize the javascript?